# tool for creating diagrams in web browser

Tags: html

I am looking for a tool for creating diagrams in the web browser.
Usually we have a palette on the left, drawing area in the middle and some preferences on the right.
A good example is this one
[image]

Answer (score 1):

From your question, my initial instinct was to recommend draw.io, but since it's been a while, I see it has become [diagrams.net](https://diagrams.net) and that's exactly what [@Aly Ahmed](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/80089/76723) suggested.

From your response and screenshot, it seems you are more interested in a floor-planner of sorts, and while there are some good installable ones, when it comes to online-browser based apps YMMV.

Take a look at the list from [AlternativeTo.net](https://alternativeto.net/software/sweet-home-3d/?platform=online) of online alternatives to ***Sweet Home 3D*** (which is NOT a browser based app).

If you DID find something, please update us with what you decided on using.

Answer (score 0):

Try this online tool it is rich with features.
We use it in our project for flow charts and data flow clarification.
It provides more place to save files.

```
https://app.diagrams.net/
```

Comment: i am looking for a tool to create such an editor based on my requirements